# How to extract hour and minute from a date field in AWS Quicksight

Tags: amazon-quicksight

I am new to Quicksight and I am trying to extract the hour and minute from a date field. I've used extract function but would only return either hour or minute. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Did You tried this as a kind of a hack?:

```
concat(toString(extract('HH',{YOURS_DATE_FIELD})),':',toString(extract('MI',{YOURS_DATE_FIELD})))
```